# SQL Select results based on two rows with different condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to fetch results where I want to check if two rows exist for a common ForeignKeyId and add a check on both rows.

Suppose I have a table below - 'Test1'

```
A    B    C    D                               'Test2'
1    33   x    NULL                             Result       Id
2    33   NULL y                                Result1      33
3    44   x    NULL                             Result2      44
4    44   NULL z                                Result3      55
5    55   x    NULL
```

I want to fetch Result from Test2 table where Test1 should contain two rows where C = x and D <> NULL.

So, select query should return Result1 and Result2, not Result3

I tried:

```
select Result
from Test2
inner join Test1 on Test2.Id = Test1.A
where 
    (select Count(*) from Test1 where C = 'x') = 1 AND 
    (select Count(*) from Test1 where D IS NOT NULL) = 1;
```

Comment: SQL Server is used

Comment: solution below might work for SQL Server, but so often results are database dependent so tagging appropriately saves everyone time. Pure SQL and DB questions should be asked on https://dba.stackexchange.com next time too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compare the same value in a different row a self join is used. In this case There are two Test1 tables, the first (`Tc`) matches the `C` criteria, and the second `Td` matches the `D` criteria.

```
SELECT Result,Tc.B
FROM Test1 Tc
JOIN Test1 Td
  ON Tc.B=Td.B
JOIN Test2
  ON Td.B=Test2.Id
WHERE
   Tc.C = 'x'
   AND Td.D IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `exists`:

```
select t2.*
from test2 t2
where exists (select 1 from test1 t1 where t2.id = t1.b and t1.c = 'x') and
      exists (select 1 from test1 t1 where t2.id = t1.b and t1.d is not null);
```

The reason for this is that you will not get duplicates if multiple rows match either condition in `table1`.

Note:  The above could return return with only one matching row in `table1` if both conditions are true for that row.  You can require two rows by having more precise conditions:

```
where exists (select 1 from test1 t1 where t2.id = t1.b and t1.c = 'x' and t1.id is null) and
      exists (select 1 from test1 t1 where t2.id = t1.b and t1.d is not null and (t1.c <> 'x' or t1.c is null));
```